# need to bind values in place of ids(comma seperated)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to replace ids with coresponding values

example:if column consist of ids 1,2
I need to replace 1 with "Product Videos",2 with "Installation" .
I can use case but not able to find a way to use case for comma seperated ids

```
SELECT BusinessFocus
    ,(
        SELECT stuff((
                    SELECT ', ' + BusinessFocus
                        ,CASE 
                            WHEN BusinessFocus = 1
                                THEN 'Product Videos'
                            WHEN BusinessFocus = 2
                                THEN 'Installation Videos'
                            WHEN BusinessFocus = 3
                                THEN 'Other Videos'
                            END AS BFocusname
                    WHERE BusinessFocus IN (
                            SELECT val
                            FROM dbo.split(PartnerMaster.BusinessFocus, ',')
                            )
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')
        ) AS BusinessFocusNames
FROM PartnerMaster
```

Actual Result:

[image: actual result]

Expected Result:

```
   1,3    |  Product Videos,Installation Videos
```

Comment: You could use a cursor with dynamic sql

Comment: are not you storing BusinessFocus names in any other table??

Comment: no. As number of records was only 3 so did not create table.

Comment: Are you just looking for convert '1,3' to 'Product Videos,Other Videos' ? If yes, why you are not trying to use REPLACE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just looking for convert '1,3' to 'Product Videos,Other Videos', you can use REPLACE as below-

```
DECLARE @BusinessFocus VARCHAR(200) = '1,3'

SELECT @BusinessFocus, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(@BusinessFocus,'1','Product Videos'),'3','Other Videos')
```

Note: You can use one more REPLACE as shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not storing these Business focus values somewhere else in table, make use of CTE.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #PartnerMaster (BusinessFocus VARCHAR(100), BusinessFocusNames VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #PartnerMaster (BusinessFocus)
SELECT '1,2' UNION ALL SELECT '3' UNION ALL SELECT '2,3'
```

Now do join with `Charindex` and make them comma separated list with `For XML Path`

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT '1' BusinessFocus, 'Product Videos' BusinessFocusNames
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' BusinessFocus, 'Installation Videos' BusinessFocusNames
UNION ALL
SELECT '3' BusinessFocus, 'Other Videos' BusinessFocusNames
)
SELECT P.BusinessFocus
, STUFF((SELECT ','+C.BusinessFocusNames FROM CTE C 
         WHERE CHARINDEX(C.BusinessFocus,P.BusinessFocus)>0
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS  BusinessFocusNames
FROM #PartnerMaster P
```

Result:

```
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| BusinessFocus |         BusinessFocusNames         |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| 1,2           | Product Videos,Installation Videos |
| 3             | Other Videos                       |
| 2,3           | Installation Videos,Other Videos   |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
```